# What percentage of our DNA is never transcribable? What percent is never actually transcribed into RNA unless researchers force it to in a lab?

Tags: dna, rna, transcription, translation

From what I gather, the vast majority (but not all) of the DNA in our genomes will transcribe and create an RNA, if only under certain conditions in a lab (forcibly unwound, among other steps).

How much of our DNA can be transcribed but not translated?

How much actually does so on a regular basis in our cells, becoming useful RNA, but doesn't code a single amino acid?  (Non-coding functional RNA, or junk RNA?)

Answer (score 5):

While, as you say, most of our DNA can be transcribed, you are right that it is not well accessible and/or lacks strong promoters. It's said that over 80% of DNA is transcribed but only <2% transcribes into mRNA, that will be translated [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(biology)). It is not yet known what percentage of non-coding RNA (ncRNA) is junk (by identity) [[2]](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2015.00002/full), but if weighted by mass or numbers, most of ncRNA is functional as ribosomes and tRNAs make up most of the cells dry mass:

[image: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2015.00002/full]
([image source](https://doi.org/10.3389/fgene.2015.00002))

Comment: Minor detail: doesn‘t the left pie chart say that rRNAs make up most of a cell‘s dry mass and not tRNAs..?

Comment: I once read in a book „Numbers in Biology“, that ribosomes can make up to 80% of cells dry mass. The chart is not about dry mass but about RNA mass, ignoring not only water but also lipids, proteins etc.

Comment: Oh I meant together they make up most of the cells mass. Not tRNA alone.